# Problem with a function number of argument

Tags: ruby

I was trying to build a function that summarize your bio on ig via **scraping** but there is a problem in the number of argument
wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 6) (ArgumentError)

The problem is that this function is actually working on my first loop for the analyze of the pseudo of the user but not on my second one but I don't know why.

```
def affectation(theme,info,usernam,userr,indice,string)
        indice.each do |index|
            if string[index]
                string.slice! index
                if info.has_key?(theme.to_sym) #we check if our hash didn't already have this category
                    info[theme.to_sym] += 1  # if he has we just add one
                    userr.status = theme.to_sym
                else
                    info[theme.to_sym] = 1 #if not we create a new category and give it the val 1
                    userr.status = theme.to_sym
                end
                affectation(indice,string)
            end
        end
    
        Dir.chdir("./#{usernam}/User_following/#{userr.identity}")
        File.write("Resume.txt",userr.status)
        Dir.chdir("../../../")
    end
```

this is the call who fail at a moment

```
affectation("Techno",@information,username,user,"TECHNO Techno techno Pouf POUF pouf".split(" "),value)
```

error info :

```
7: from login_2.rb:720:in `<main>'
        6: from login_2.rb:519:in `user_info'
        5: from login_2.rb:519:in `each'
        4: from login_2.rb:560:in `block in user_info'
        3: from login_2.rb:444:in `affectation'
        2: from login_2.rb:444:in `each'
        1: from login_2.rb:465:in `block in affectation'
login_2.rb:442:in `affectation': wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 6) (ArgumentError)
```

Comment: Apart from the wrong number of arguments – you are calling `affectation` _recursively_ within the `indice.each` loop. Is that expected?

Answer (score 3):

In line 1, you define `affectation` to take 6 parameters:

```ruby
def affectation(theme, info, usernam, userr, indice, string)
#               ↑ 1 ↑  ↑ 2↑  ↑  3  ↑  ↑ 4 ↑  ↑  5 ↑  ↑  6 ↑
```

In line 23, you call `affectation` with 2 arguments:

```ruby
affectation(indice, string)
#           ↑  1 ↑  ↑  2 ↑
```

Therefore, you get the error that the method is expecting 6 arguments, but is only getting 2.